# Python - draw numbers in specific pattern on x y graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, graph

I wonder how can i draw as many as it's possible numbers on x y graph. It have to be cross pattern, something like this: 1 = (x0,y1); 2 = (x1,y0); 3 = (x0,y-1); 4 = (x-1,y0); 5 = (x0,y2); 6 = (x2,y0); and so on...
I have tried with matplotlib, but without any results.

Current code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0]
y = [1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 5]
plt.plot(x, y, "o", color="black")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
for x, y in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(x, y, str(x), color="red", fontsize=12)
plt.title('graph!')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: To plot one point at a time you could try `plt.scatter`.  Please show your best-effort code together with some test data.

Comment: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


x = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0]
y = [1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 5]

plt.plot(x, y, "o", color="black")

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')

for x, y in zip(x, y):
    plt.text(x, y, str(x), color="red", fontsize=12)

plt.title('graph!')

plt.show()`

Comment: on generated graph numbers are just values of position on axis. I wanted to draw index number of every point. First point =1 second point =2...

Comment: Please don't put the code into a comment. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70095668/edit) your post and copy it there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you want to annotate the points with their index in the list.

Use `enumerate`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [0, 1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0]
y = [1, 0, -1, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 3, 0, -3, 0, 4, 0, -4, 0, 5]
plt.plot(x, y, "o", color="black")
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
for i, (x, y) in enumerate(zip(x, y)):
    plt.text(x, y, i+1, color="red", fontsize=12)
plt.title('graph!')
plt.show()
```

output:

[image: enumerated points]

Comment: That is excactly what i needed, thanks a lot. One more question, is there any way to select every even number in other color for example purple?

Comment: Yes, use `color="purple" if i%2 else "red"` (I didn't test of purple is a valid color)